# I can't open a windows in tkinter for an other

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with my GUI application with Tkinter. I don't understand why I can open another window.
When name user and password are ok the connexion windows open a other windows but the windows never show

I think it's because I use two tk instances but It's work very fine this morning.

here some lines of codes for the connexion windows

```
# init the windows
global app
app = Connexion()
app.title("Se connecter")
app.mainloop()

# calling the other windows
Acceuil.appel_affichage_accueil(id_utilisateur)
global app
app.quit()
```

the init of the other windows

```
def appel_affichage_accueil(IDUtilisateurEnvoye):
    """
        On va afficher un message d'alerte dans la fenetre d'alerte
        la variable afficher correspont auIdUtilisateur message que l'on souhaite faire apparaitre
    """
    global Idutilisateur
    Idutilisateur = IDUtilisateurEnvoye
    AffichageAcceuil()

class AffichageAcceuil(tk.Tk):
    # ligne de code qui se lance lorsque de l'initialisation
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution:

just replace `app.quit()` by `app.destroy()`

Comment: Thank you for the english it's not my native language...I can't mark as correct answer before 2 days....

Comment: Happy to help, you can wait for 2 days then :D